# windows 2012 rails server -P and -b not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am running Rails 5.0 in windows 20112 R2. I am in developement mode and want to use and IP rather than localhost and want to change the port also.

The -P is completely ignored and the -b is taken but I get and error trying to bring up my welcome page that says " Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255"

I can't find anything on using something other than localhost in development mode. Is this a built in restriction or am I missing something?

Here are excerpts of what I see.

```
`D:\DTS_WEB>rails server -P 3010 -b 172.28.60.97
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0 application starting in development on http://172.28.60.97:3000
                                                                          ^^^^^
No route matches [GET] "/welcome"
Rails.root: D:/DTS_WEB

GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.2"
HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip, deflate"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "en-US"
HTTP_VERSION: "HTTP/1.1"
ORIGINAL_SCRIPT_NAME: ""
REMOTE_ADDR: "172.28.60.97"
SERVER_NAME: "172.28.60.97"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"

Started GET "/welcome" for 172.28.60.97 at 2016-09-22 14:30:44 -0600
Cannot render console from 172.28.60.97! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port is controlled with the *lowercase* `p` option. You probably want to use this:

```
rails server -p 3010 -b 0.0.0.0
```

The `-b 0.0.0.0` option will allow connections on any address.

Comment: Oh geez, I've been reading that as a capital P all along. I've give the 0.0.0.0 a try but do you know if this is just a development environment issue?

Comment: Typically you would never use `rails server` in production, so yes, it is a development issue. In production you'd run e.g. puma or unicorn directly.